# how can I log in with two ways?

Tags: backend, nest

I want to write code, that give me a chance to log in with email and phoneNumber.
When I send request with phoneNumber from frontend for login in I see this:

```java
function verified(err, user, info) {
   if (err) { return self.error(err); }
   if (!user) { return self.fail(info); }
   self.success(user, info);
}
```

My request with phoneNumber. It's not working.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

My request with email. It's working well.

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

How can I log in with phone and email?

My localStrategy:

```java
@Injectable()
export class LocalStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
   constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
    super({
      usernameField: 'email',
    });
   }
   
async validate(
   email: string,
   password: string,
   phoneNumber: string,
   ): Promise<any> {
   
   console.log(` mail ${email}`) // here I see mail
   console.log(` pass ${password}`) // here I see passport 
   console.log(` phone ${phoneNumber}`) // here I see function verified, look down

   function verified(err, user, info) {
   if (err) { return self.error(err); }
   if (!user) { return self.fail(info); }
   self.success(user, info);
   }

   const user = await this.authService.validateUser(
     email,
     password,
     phoneNumber,
   );
   
   if (!user) {
     throw new UnauthorizedException('Неверный логин или пароль');
   }
   
   return user;
   }
}
```

auth.service

```java
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    constructor(
      private usersService: UsersService,
      private jwtService: JwtService,
    ) {}
    
    async validateUser(
     email: string,
     password: string,
     phoneNumber: string,
    ): Promise<any> {
    console.log(phoneNumber)
    let user;
    if (email) {
      user = await this.usersService.findByEmail(email);
      // return user;
    } else {
      user = await this.usersService.findByPhone(phoneNumber);
    }
    
    if (!user) throw new UnauthorizedException('Пользователь не найден')
    const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password ,user.password);
    if (!isMatch) throw new UnauthorizedException('Не верный логи или пароль')
    
    if (isMatch) {
      return user
    }
    }
    
    async register(dto: CreateUserDto) {
      ***code*** it's okay
    }
    
    async login(user: UserEntity) {
    
    return {
      token: this.jwtService.sign({ id: user.id }),
    };
  }
}
```

```
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BOz4.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgf78.png
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to make two different endpoints, one for logging in by phone, the other by email and, accordingly, two different guards. The validation of the front part should already determine where to send it. From the point of view of building a Rest Api, this will be a good solution.;
But if you still need to do this in one endpoint, then in general you are already close to a solution, first of all, checking if else in ValidateUser is incorrect due to the fact that you may not have an email or phone number. Therefore, it would be better to make the following check in your LocalStrategy:

```
if (email) {
      user = await this.authService.validateUserByEmail(email, password)
} else if (phoneNumber) {
      user = await this.authService.validateUserByPhone(phoneNumber, password)
} else throw UnauthorizedException('...')
```

в autoservice соответственно нужно создать методы validateUserByEmail и validateUserByPhone.
Также не забудь в методе  validate сделать user и phone необязательными параметрами. Тогда при отправке запроса не обязательно будет писать и email и phoneNumber.

Comment: Answer is in two languages.  Looks like the second half  of the translation was missed.